# How do I move Rails App from Developement to Production environment of HostGator not Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment

I'm trying to put my Rails App to HostGator, but I am not sure how I should do this. I created a Rails test app and uploaded it to Heroku and it works just fine. 
Now I'm trying to learn how to move from development to production environment of HostGator.

I'd really appreciate your time and share your thought on this process from development to production environment of my web hosting HostGator. Thanks!!!

Comment: Dont do this. Hostgator is not ruby supporting hoster. http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-and-gems. If you don't want to use Heroku for some reason - you can use another modern hosters. DigitalOcean, Google Apps, AWS.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Honestly - I'll recommend you to stay on heroku. It will save you from a lot of problems.